# Algorithms to convert 2D videos to 3D ones

Tags: algorithms, image-processing, computer-vision, graphics

Are there published algorithms that can convert 2D videos to 3D ones? If there are few published algorithms for this I am also interested to know how the conversion quality is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153740/is-there-any-algorithm-for-converting-2d-video-into-3d-video

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there are many algorithms for this:

1. Some works, which directly work on H264 domain, such as:

> Real-Time 2D to 3D Conversion from H.264
>   Video Compression, *Nir Shabat, Gil Shabat and Amir Averbuch*
>   http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~amir1/PS/3d.pdf

2. Some deep learning methods already exist on the topic: 
   http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jxie/pdf/deep3d.pdf
   (this is the review version of the paper, so I could not cite)
3. There are many other works which use images in many ways to create 3D:

http://live.ece.utexas.edu/publications/2011/cao_mag_2011.pdf

https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~pdidyk/papers/2D-to-3D/2D-to-3D.pdf